# Jquery toggle html

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
jQuery(this).html(jQuery(this).html() == '&#9660; SHOW &#9660;' ? '&#9650; HIDE &#9650;' : '&#9660; SHOW &#9660;');
```

This will toggle the text as requested but it shows the

```
&#9660;
```

as the html and not as the ▼

anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to use symbolic representation (e.g. `"▼ SHOW ▼"`) instead of the codes? Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WXYBb/.

Comment: VisioN - It works as it should but the charictors then just show as a ?

Comment: Then you should check the charset. You should save the sources in UTF-8.

Comment: Here is a Jsfiddle of the whole thing: http://jsfiddle.net/nGh2n/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the html (or text) content you get from the element content is already transformed. So the `&#9660;` doesn't exist anymore.

If this script is in UTF-8, you may do this :

```
$(this).html(jQuery(this).text() == '▼ SHOW ▼' ? '▲ HIDE ▲' : '▼ SHOW ▼');
```

**EDIT, Another simpler version not needing UTF-8 :**

```
$(this).html(jQuery(this).text().indexOf('SHOW')>0 ? '&#9650; HIDE &#9650;' : '&#9660; SHOW &#9660;');
```

Comment: Thanks but i an unable in this instance to change the script to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
$('#foo').toggle(function() {
    $(this).html('&#9650; HIDE &#9650;');
}, function() {
    $(this).html('&#9660; SHOW &#9660;');
});
```

***[The live demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/SfKGQ/)***

Comment: Unfortunately `toggle()` is deprecated now.

Comment: @VisioN Unfortunately it is, so what is the best way of toggle a html content?

Comment: Maybe `if-else`... Seriously, I can't get the reason for deprecating *really* useful methods in jQuery. Another example so far is `:text` selector.

Comment: Hi, regading toogle: toogle itself doesn't seem to be depircated ( http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ ). However the toggle event, where you can bind muliple events to a element, which are executed on alternate clicks (http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ ) is depricated.